# Packages and Interface(Access Protection)

Tags: java

What is the difference between non-subclasses in the same package and subclasses in a different package?

Comment: yes but what is the question?

Comment: I don't know how you could post the question as you are new member(today)? Your question is very small. For new members there are some restrictions.

Comment: You need to learn a basics of java

Comment: Hello Nirali, and Welcome to SO. We encourage you to do some research before you post your question here. And then, if you face any problem, then post that specific problem, with proper description of your issue. See [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Comment: @NandkumarTekale/ I think there are no restriction on asking questions.

Comment: @RohitJain : yes there are, check http://stackoverflow.com/privileges also check this http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user

Comment: @NandkumarTekale.. Just 1 reputation?? Which is given by default to every new user as I remember. Yeah, and those links no where says, that a new user cannot even ask questions.

Comment: @RohitJain : the fact is this is very small question. When I had asked my 1st ques, I had restrictions. Restrictions include minimum number of chars and usage of code in question. Check second link in my above comment.

Comment: @RohitJain : confirm it on meta, they may changed restrictions earlier for new users, I don't know

Comment: @NandkumarTekale Your second link says nothing about the size of the question. Anyway, the conversation is pointless as clearly no restriction exists otherwise the question could not be asked. Take this conversation to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ if you want to discuss it further.

Answer (score 2):

Given a class, `A`

- Non-subclasses in the same package as `A` can access public and package-private methods of `A`
- Subclasses of `A` in a different package can access public and protected methods of `A`.

---

Note: there is no keyword for package-private protection - it is the protection chosen when no other is specified.

```
public void thisIsPublic(...)

protected void thisIsProtected(...)

void thisIsPackagePrivate(...)
```

*Recommended reading: [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)*

Answer (score 2):

"Non-subclasses in the same package and subclasses in a different package", rather the question is "What will happen when we declare non-subclasses in same package & subclasses in different packages?
This matters when you are dealing with **Scope Specifiers**. Here is the table that shows the difference.

```
                       Private     No Modifier    Protected     Public

1. Same class           Yes             Yes         Yes          Yes

2. Same package         No              Yes         Yes          Yes
   subclass
3. Same package         No              Yes         Yes          Yes
   non-subclass
4. Different package    No              No          Yes          Yes
   subclass
5. Different package    No              No          No           Yes
   non-subclass
```

This table is from book "Java The Complete Reference" by "Herbert Schildt"